# How can I polymorphically structure a database?

Tags: database, excel, design-patterns, polymorphism

This might be a stupid question but I have very little experience. I have encountered an issue where I am working with a Excel spreadsheet for a small factory.

It has a huge list of products that are grouped into families.

analogy: Corolla, Avensis, Landcruiser = Toyota

Furthermore the products have a list of tasks associated with them.

Corolla: 
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3...

All products share tasks in the first few stages even across different families. 
But some occur at a different stage during production
What may be step 6 in productX is step 5 in productY.
But productX and productY share 1-5. (And this is true across the board.

I have three questions.
Is it possible to polymorphically structure a database? Common tasks can be placed in the base class and get more specific (common for OO).

If it is not can you create a central database of unordered tasks and give some sort of priority  to each database of a product and they give the tasks some order.

Final question is has anyone encountered such a problem? I have a feeling there has to be a design pattern to this. It feels like a solution is just beyond my grasp.

Edit 1. Spread sheet is mostly blank for time being. Worksheets are the product names. That string-integer combination are the product numbers. Values will be put in underneath i.e. Time/hr and the amount of product *should* be made in the time specified [[image: Screen grab]

Comment: Sample spreadsheet would be helpful.

Comment: Added a screen grab :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is what I understood:

- You need to store a mapping between products and tasks/steps. The latter should be stored in order that are to be performed.
- Some initial tasks are always common for all products.
- You'd like to structure your database 'polymorphically'. Since you didn't mention what kind of database you are using, I'll assume it to be a relational one.

You can create your tables so:

- `Product`: each row stores data on one product. Primary key: `product-name` (or `product-id`, whatever)
- `Task`: information on a task, such as time taken to finish it etc. Primary key: `task-name/id`.
- `ProductTaskMapping`: contains mapping of what tasks are to be done what product, in order. Its schema will be as follows. You can also think of having the first two columns as foreign keys.

  - `product-name`- refers to the primary-key in `Product` table.
  - `task-name`- refers to the primary-key in `Task` table.
  - `priority`, or `sequence-number`
- `CommonTask`: Two columns:

  - `task-name`
  - `priority`

Also, there's no way to define 'inheritance' between two tables.